# linker command failed with exit code: 1

Tags: ios, angular, xcode, ionic-framework, capacitor

I'm encountering a linker error while trying to build an iOS application developed using Ionic, Capacitor, and Angular. The build process fails for both debug (testing on the device) and release builds.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
"_crc32", referenced from:
  _unzReadCurrentFile in ICDeviceManager(unzip.o)
"_deflate", referenced from:
  IComon::logger::LogBuffer::Write(void const*, unsigned long) in ICDeviceManager(log_buffer.o)
"_deflateEnd", referenced from:
  IComon::logger::LogBuffer::~LogBuffer() in ICDeviceManager(log_buffer.o)
IComon::logger::LogBuffer::Flush(IComon::logger::AutoBuffer&) in ICDeviceManager(log_buffer.o)
"deflateInit2", referenced from:
  IComon::logger::LogBuffer::__Reset() in ICDeviceManager(log_buffer.o)
"_get_crc_table", referenced from:
  _unzOpenCurrentFile3 in ICDeviceManager(unzip.o)
"_inflate", referenced from:
  _unzReadCurrentFile in ICDeviceManager(unzip.o)
"_inflateEnd", referenced from:
  _unzCloseCurrentFile in ICDeviceManager(unzip.o)
"inflateInit2", referenced from:
  _unzOpenCurrentFile3 in ICDeviceManager(unzip.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Project Info:

```
Xcode: 14.3.1
IOS SDK: 16.4
Capacitor: 5.2.2
Ionic: 7 
Angular: 16
```

I've tried multiple solutions to address the linker error. However, none of them have worked so far.
Thank you for your attention to this matter. Your assistance is greatly appreciated.